# Python / Pandas: problem with column headers from an Excel CSV UTF-8 file

Tags: python, pandas, utf-8

This is my first venture into UTF-8 in Pandas, so maybe a newbe error.

I have a simple test table in Excel which I saved as UTF-8 CSV. Looking at the file with "less" on Linux gives me this:

```
<U+FEFF>sample;chead
1;test
```

while a "hexdump -C" this:

```
00000000  ef bb bf 73 61 6d 70 6c  65 3b 63 68 65 61 64 0d  |...sample;chead.|
00000010  0a 31 3b 74 65 73 74 0d  0a                       |.1;test..|
```

So far, so good, I will assume that this is a correct UTF-8 file.

I now want to read that file into a pandas dataframe and check the name of the first column to be "sample" or "probe".

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("sample1.csv", encoding="utf-8", sep=None, engine="python")

cols = [x.lower() for x in df.columns.values]
print("Columns:", cols)
print("Columns[0]:", cols[0])
print("type Columns[0]:", type(cols[0]))

# I expect this not to print, but it does
if cols[0] not in ["sample", "probe"]:
     print("Ouch, cols[0] is not 'sample' or 'probe'???")
```

And the output of the above program is:

```
Columns: ['\ufeffsample', 'chead']
Columns[0]: sample
type Columns[0]: <class 'str'>
Ouch, cols[0] is not 'sample' or 'probe'???
```

From the first line of the output I do understand (somehow) that the cols[0] value is '\ufeffsample', but as the output via print() statement is "sample", I do not understand why the "if" triggers.

What do I need to change so that the "if" statement works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<U+FEFF>` is a byte order mark, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark.

To read in a file in pandas with those, you can set the encoding to `utf-8-sig` as suggested in https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/4793.